# Navigation bar's title being hidden behind the back title

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationbar

Newbie here.
I'm creating a link between two views. The first view Current Books contains a list of books, and a + button which when clicked takes you to a new view called Add Book.
[image: before segue]

This is what it looks like before I add a segue between these two views.
[image: after segue]

This is what it looks like after I add a segue between these two, connected by the +

As you can see, the title 'Add Book' of my second activity goes invisible upon adding the segue. How would I get it to be visible again?

I also noticed that upon double clicking of the position of the invisible title, I am able to edit the title's text but it still won't make it appear! Please help!  [image: edit]

Comment: What happens when you run this?

Comment: @Losiowaty when I run this, the title does not appear

Comment: Add navigation title programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you added your own navigation bar in AddBookViewController scene of Storyboard. if so, just delete that navigation bar then drag segue from CurrentBooks `+` button, now select your AddBookViewController in Storyboard [image: select your viewcontroller]

then select show attribute inspector, and change your ViewController title.   [image: Attribute inspector]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Swift -->    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
Objective C --> [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

add line on Add Book ViewController

Comment: Under what function do I add it in swift? Also I do not have a AddBookViewController Class

Answer (score 0):

You can setup title programatically in AddBookViewController.

```
self.title = "The title you want"
```

Put this in View Did Load

Comment: Or if you prefer to use storyboard, you have to place a navigation item in your viewcontroller.